# How to correctly specify an interaction term in glmer?

Tags: regression, logistic, lme4-nlme

I'm most familiar with SAS coding but recently decided to run a similar model in R using the `lme4` package. My current model in SAS is specified as:

```
PROC GLIMMIX DATA=STUDYAREA;

CLASS ID YEAR SITE SEASON1;

MODEL R0A1 = MP_SCALED|SEASON1 MPHW_SCALED|SEASON1 
             HW_SCALED|SEASON1 YP_SCALED|SEASON1 SHRUB_SCALED|SEASON1 / 
 DIST=BINOMIAL LINK=LOGIT SOLUTION ODDSRATIO;

  RANDOM ID / TYPE = VC;
  RANDOM SITE / TYPE = VC;
  NLOPTIONS GCONV=0;
RUN;
```

In order to get both the main effects and the interaction terms in the output in R, what is an equivalent way to build the same model from SAS into R? This is what I have so far but wasn't sure if you the colon was the correct way to get both fixed effects and interactions in the output.

```
results<-glmer(R0A1~MP_Scaled:Season1+MPHW_Scaled:Season1+
    HW_Scaled:Season1+YP_Scaled:Season1+
    AG_Scaled:Season1+Shrub_Scaled:Season1+
    (1|ID)+(1|Site),
  data=turkey2nd,family=binomial)
summary(results)
```

Comment: You need to also specify the main effects.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium, do you request the main effects and the interaction in R by just using an asterisk (*) symbol? Thanks!

Comment: The colon represents the interaction effect, and most standard packages that use the formula argument will understand this syntax. The variable name in its own term represents the main effect.

Comment: So if you have y dependent variable, and independent variables x1 and x2, and you wanted all main effects and interactions, the formula is y ~ x1 + x2 + x1: x2

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium, thanks for the helpful information!